# Magento 2.4: Company user not able to see the transaction done by Company admin

Tags: magento2, customer-account, user-roles, b2b, company

I'm using Magento 2 Enterprise Edition. Using B2B feature, I have created a Company account and added a Company user for that company. As a Company admin, I can see all the orders placed by company user in the account dashboard but when I login as a Company user I cannot see any transactions done by Company admin.

[image]

Is this a default behaviour of Magento? Please guide

Comment: what is the role you assigned to your company user?

Comment: @DianaBotean, I have created the custom role with all permissions which is available but still the company user couldn't able to see the transactions of company admin.

Comment: Good question @Siva I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?